# How to prevent excel from showing dates as number

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I'm using excel to get data from an external SQL server table, using power query, in the query window it shows date/time fields normally, but in the excel sheet, it shows it as a number, even when I change the type and cast and make a refresh it transform it again as a number.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think there is two way: format the excel column (I don't know how you write data to excel) or adding simple quote ' before data

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you're writing the data? The query and the code for populating..

Comment: You have to format resulting cells (or full column) as DATE.

Comment: Maythe you formatted output column with number format which you need to remove now..

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  If I have a PQ column formatted as date, or datetime, when I `close and load` it will format the Excel column the same way.  It is only if the column is formatted as `any` that I will see the date serial number.  I have Office 365 but I'd be surprised if that was the issue.

Comment: i did all these but once i close and reopen and do a refresh i get the same result

Comment: I should have written *`PQ column with a **data type of date, or datetime**, I cannot repro your problem*.

Comment: you need to set the table to remember the formatting

Answer (score 0):

Once in Excel from SQL, select all rows in the expected date column.  Once all are highlighted, right click, select format cells, choose date format.  Voila